# Will Fernco couplers survive concrete?

Tags: plumbing, concrete

My contractor hit my sewer line when digging a footing and repaired it using Fernco™ couplers.

Will those survive when encased in concrete or will the concrete eat away at the rubber and/or steel bands holding them on?

I don't have a good feeling about it, so I'm off to buy a couple of slip-joint PVC connectors, but I'm not sure if I should use them or not.

Comment: Regardless of the answer (which I don't know) I believe PVC pipes encased in footings are supposed to be sleeved in larger PVC pipes.  My guess is that Ferncos and slip joints would both benefit from those sleeves too.

Comment: I am not sure either, but jay613 seems to have a good idea.  If something did happen, I think being able to pull the pipe instead of breaking up footing makes sense.

Comment: I guess it depends on where you are on the planet.  Here in Fla. it is common and code to pour cement around schedule 40 PVC.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/213797/23295 - concrete is not back fill, nor part of a joint that isn't clay pipe. Will the SS bands eventually rust? yes. Will that leak any more than what every three feet of clay pipe in the world already does? no. Should you use slip couplings? yes. Would some Fernco's last for +20y? Probably also yes. Prob says they're suitable for *direct* burial. *not* encased in concrete. Below a slab, sitting on a granular bed, yes.

Comment: @Mazura I'm not sure which way you're leaning there. Not being snarky, I'm really not sure...

Comment: Depends on if you're like my geriatric father and "on the ten year plan". Then the SS rusting in 20y isn't your problem. Either way, unless it's clay pipe, it doesn't get concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on the type of Fernco.

Some are designed to be buried and have stainless clamps and are approved by most local code.

Once dry the concrete makes it's own shield around the coupling and it is unlikely to crush or be disturbed.  Additionallly, since this pipe is not under pressure there is little likelihood of a leak.

Will the concrete degrade the rubber?  Not likely in decades, if not after a century.

The definitive answer would be from the local building dept. dependent on their approval.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I got the couplings, it rained and I didn't get a chance to get into the muddy trench to replace them. It passed inspection and the concrete's been poured. I'll just count on it working well until I move. ;)